# Handle redirect manually

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I built a class which uses an `HttpClient` instance for downloading the content of a page. This is working pretty well but I'm not really satisfied about my implementation of redirect.

In fact, I handle the redirect manually as you can see:

```
/// <summary>
/// Web request handler
/// </summary>
public class NetworkHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Store the url.
    /// </summary>
    private static Uri _storedUrl = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Store the html data.
    /// </summary>
    private static string _storedData = "";

    public static string GetHtml(Uri url)
    {
        if (url == _storedUrl)
            return _storedData;
        else
            _storedUrl = url;

        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = url,
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

            int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

            if (statusCode >= 300 && statusCode <= 399)
            {
                Uri redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;

                if (!redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                {
                    redirectUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + redirectUri);
                }

                return GetHtml(redirectUri);
            }

            using (WebClient wClient = new WebClient())
            {
                wClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                _storedData = wClient.DownloadString(url);
            }

            return _storedData;
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve my implementation for handling the redirect?

Comment: What you have is not bad. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968318/cannot-manage-redirect/49968480#49968480) if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks solid, however here are a few minor points.

**Catching/throwing exceptions**

You should only catch exceptions when you are going to handle them. There's no point in catching an exception when you're *only* going to (re)throw it. However if you were to use logging and still 'bubble up' the exception, you could go with this:

```
try
{
    //Your webrequest/response code...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //DO YOUR LOGGING HERE

    throw;
}
```

But as of now I would remove the `try/catch` from the method and handle exceptions outside of it:

```
try
{
    string theHtml = NetworkHelper.GetHtml("http://example.com");
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
   //Handle the exception
}
```

---

**Stored url and data**

As of now, your code doesn't allow the same url twice in a row; it'll just return the stored data. This raises 2 questions/issues with me:

- What if I *want to refresh* the result?
- I can bypass the check easily but in a hacky way:

  1. Pass url1
  2. Pass url2 to change the `_storedUrl` variable
  3. Call the method again with url1

I think better would be to change the signature of the method and add a boolean (optional) parameter to indicate if you want to refresh the result:

```
public static string GetHtml(Uri url, bool refresh = false)
{
    if (url == _storedUrl && !refresh)
        return _storedData;
    else
        _storedUrl = url;

    //Rest of the logic...
 }
```

Now you will only return the `_storedData` if you have the same url and don't want to refresh.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I rethrow the exception because I handle the exception in other classes which user NeworkHelper. I store the url and the data just for performance reason, infact my bot could access to the same link and get the same data, for not execute again the request I just return the previous html.

Comment: I understand that you handle it in other classes, but if that is the case there's not point in catching it in this method. Just remove the try/catch and your code will remain working.